# How should I mount relays in junction boxes?

Tags: electrical

If one had a [typical AC relay](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/2-1611750-5/PB1650-ND/2399030) (120/240VAC contacts, 120VAC or 24VAC coil, chassis mount), how would they mount it inside a junction box (assume a blank faceplate) and attach wires to it in a way that's Code compliant?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a 6x6x4 junction box and mount the relay to the back with Tek (drill point) screws. This should give you plenty of room for wiring and terminations.

Comment: Makes sense so far, but what types of terminations would be legal under the Code? Many of these relays use tab (quick connect, faston) terminals, and I am not sure if that type of device termination meets the NEC.

Comment: Why wouldn't they? If they are 1/4" tab then female tab terminals are what to use. There is nothing in the NEC that dictates a certain type of terminal must be used or not allowed. You just cannot rely on solder alone, it must be a mechanical connection.

Comment: Oh!  Thanks!  I was simply not sure if tab terminals were considered along with rings and spades when the NEC speaks of crimped (pressure) connections.

Comment: If they're industry standard relays (tab) spade terminated for industrial use, they will have a mating socket they plug into available. The sockets are designed to fit into a sort of bracket that allows for solid mounting. The terminations on the socket will be screw lugs similar to what you find on circuit breakers.

Comment: @Fiasco, look at the link in the question. These are self contained relays with mounting lugs. Not DIN rail bases and ice cubes relays.

Comment: Oh, that's pretty simple then. Use Amp PIDG style 1/4" female spade crimp terminals (from spec sheet, double check the width, 5/16" is also common) and stranded wiring for the connectors. With the proper crimper, these terminals form a gas tight contact and being dual layer, form a mechanical connection that doesn't relax. No auto style stuff please.